# Return count and average of field in subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have .json-file that I have imported into my collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5739ee85daa49f685e316fc6"),
    "id" : 38,
    "title" : "It Takes Two (1995)",
    "genre" : "Comedy",
    "ratings" : [
        {
            "userId" : 26,
            "rating" : 2
        },
        {
            "userId" : 531,
            "rating" : 2
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1054,
            "rating" : 2
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1068,
            "rating" : 2
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1221,
            "rating" : 5
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1434,
            "rating" : 4
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1448,
            "rating" : 1
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1645,
            "rating" : 5
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1647,
            "rating" : 1
        },
        {
            "userId" : 1958,
            "rating" : 3
        },
        {
            "userId" : 2010,
            "rating" : 1
        },
        {
            "userId" : 2042,
            "rating" : 1
        },
        {
            "userId" : 2063,
            "rating" : 1
        },
        {
            "userId" : 2106,
            "rating" : 1
        },
        {
            "userId" : 2116,
            "rating" : 3
        },
        {
            "userId" : 2541,
            "rating" : 5
        },
        {
            "userId" : 2777,
            "rating" : 3
        },
        {
             "userId" : 3013,
             "rating" : 2
        },
        {
             "userId" : 3029,
             "rating" : 2
        },
        {
             "userId" : 3111,
             "rating" : 4
        },
        {
             "userId" : 4387,
             "rating" : 1
        },
        {
             "userId" : 4572,
             "rating" : 5
        },
        {
             "userId" : 5361,
             "rating" : 5
        }
      ]
}
```

I want to do some map reduce in order to show all users with the total number of their reviews and its average value.

I tried:

```
 var map = function(){emit(this.ratings.userId, 1);}

 var reduce = function(key, values){var res = 0;
 values.forEach(function(v){ res += 1});
 return {count: res};
 }

 db.movie.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: "users" });

 db.users.find()
 { "_id" : null, "value" : { "count" : 39 } }
```

I have no idea, why it shows **_id" : null**. I suppose **this.ratings.userId** was wrong. But this.ratings[userId] doesnt work either.

I expect something like:

```
userId:10, count:2000
userId:20, count:500
```

Can you please help?

Comment: You probably don't need mapReduce for this. What do you mean by *number of their reviews and its average value*?

Comment: For examle userId "1" rated "Toy Story"(4.0), "Godfather"(5.0), "American Beauty" (5.0), "Find Nemo" (4.0). So the total number of his reviews is 4 and average value is 4.5

Comment: Please try to post the the output of  `db.movie.find().pretty()` so that we can see what your data look like. Btw use the edit link on your question. Do not post in the comment.

Comment: Ok, I posted my data.

Comment: You error is in the map function "ratings" does not have a "userId" property if you are using mapReduce. Your reduce function also need to be fixed. And last to get the average with mapReduce alongside the "count" you will need to do more than that.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong tools. You need to use the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method which gives access to the aggregation pipeline. In your pipeline you need to de-normalise the "ratings" array using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator. From there you simple group your documents by "userId" and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) and [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) accumulator operators which respectively return the sum and the average of your field.

```js
db.movie.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$ratings" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$ratings.userId", 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }, 
        "average": { "$avg": "$ratings.rating" } 
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
    var mapFunction = function() {
                       for (var idx = 0; idx < this.ratings.length; idx++) {
                           var key = this.ratings[idx].userId;
                           var value = {
                                         count: 1,
                                         rating: this.ratings[idx].rating
                                       };
                           emit(key, value);
                       }
                    };


   var reduceFunction = function(keyUSERID, countObjVals) {
                     reducedVal = { count: 0, rating: 0 };

                     for (var idx = 0; idx < countObjVals.length; idx++) {
                         reducedVal.count += countObjVals[idx].count;
                         reducedVal.rating += countObjVals[idx].rating;
                     }

                     return reducedVal;
                  };

   var finalizeFunction = function (key, reducedVal) {

                       reducedVal.avg = reducedVal.rating/reducedVal.count;

                       return reducedVal;

                    };

   db.movies.mapReduce( mapFunction,
                     reduceFunction,
                     {
                       out: "users",
                       finalize: finalizeFunction

                     }

                   )
```

db.users.find() gives me:

```
    { "_id" : 1, "value" : { "count" : 56, "rating" : 237, "avg" : 4.232142857142857 } }
    { "_id" : 2, "value" : { "count" : 129, "rating" : 479, "avg" : 3.7131782945736433 } }
    { "_id" : 3, "value" : { "count" : 51, "rating" : 199, "avg" : 3.9019607843137254 } }
    { "_id" : 4, "value" : { "count" : 21, "rating" : 88, "avg" : 4.190476190476191 } }
    { "_id" : 5, "value" : { "count" : 198, "rating" : 623, "avg" : 3.1464646464646466 } }
```